# Django How can I log client ip address?

Tags: python, django, logging

I save the logs to the file with this configuration.
But I could not log the client ip address.

I also want to keep logs for 1 day.

Is there a simple method for this? Does anyone have an idea about this?

***django-requestlogging***

I tried this library but failed. I do not know if it is up to date. Thanks

> ```
>  LOGGING ={
> 'version':1,
> 'loggers':{
>     'django':{
>         'handlers':['file','file2'],
>         'level':'DEBUG'
>     }
> },
> 'handlers':{
>     'file':{
>         'level':'INFO',
>         'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
>         'filename':'./logs/info.log',
>         'formatter':'simpleRe',
>     },
>     'file2':{
>         'level':'DEBUG',
>         'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
>         'filename':'./logs/debug6.log',
>         'formatter':'simpleRe',
>     }
> },
> 'formatters':{
>     'simpleRe': {
>         'format': ' {asctime} {levelname} {message} ',
>         'style': '{',
>     }
>
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 options:

1. Add the client's ip to each log text message. It works if your code has a request object.

```
import logging

def foo(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        
    some_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    some_logger.warning('Your log message... IP:' + ip)
```

2. Use the [django.request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django-request) or django.server extensions and their extra context feature. So the log section in settings.py might look like this:

```
import logging

class IPAddressFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'request'):
            x_forwarded_for = record.request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
            if x_forwarded_for:
                record.ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
            else:
                record.ip = record.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return True


LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "request_formatter": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s  - %(name)s - %(ip)s - %(levelname)s -  %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "request": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "request_formatter",
            "filename": "requests.txt",
            "maxBytes": 1024000,
            "backupCount": 3
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'add_ip_address': {
            '()': 'settings.IPAddressFilter' # You can move IPAddressFilter class from settings.py to another location (e.g., apps.other.filters.IPAddressFilter)
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        'django.request': {
            "level": "WARNING",
            'filters': ['add_ip_address'],
             "handlers": ["request"]
        },
    },
    "disable_existing_loggers": False
}
```

Comment: For me, testing `hasattr(record, 'request')` on localhost is always `False`. What is the cause?

Comment: I have my own custom logger. I do not want to use `django.request` . Can I still have access to the IP?

Comment: @ar2015, django.request doesn't magically inject request to the logRecord. It's just Django manually uses `extra` attribute to insert request when an error occurs. This is the source code of django where extra includes a request object. `logger.error("You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but ""it only supports HTTP.", extra=extra,)` . If you manually call getLogger('django.request') it will not include request attribute.     [A reference](https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/r2gr6x5K9_Y)

Answer (score 0):

You could use filters or adapters as described in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information). The filter example is:

```
import logging
from random import choice

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.

    Rather than use actual contextual information, we just use random
    data in this demo.
    """

    USERS = ['jim', 'fred', 'sheila']
    IPS = ['123.231.231.123', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1']

    def filter(self, record):

        record.ip = choice(ContextFilter.IPS)
        record.user = choice(ContextFilter.USERS)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    levels = (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s IP: %(ip)-15s User: %(user)-8s %(message)s')
    a1 = logging.getLogger('a.b.c')
    a2 = logging.getLogger('d.e.f')

    f = ContextFilter()
    a1.addFilter(f)
    a2.addFilter(f)
    a1.debug('A debug message')
    a1.info('An info message with %s', 'some parameters')
    for x in range(10):
        lvl = choice(levels)
        lvlname = logging.getLevelName(lvl)
        a2.log(lvl, 'A message at %s level with %d %s', lvlname, 2, 'parameters')
```

When run, this prints output like

```
2010-09-06 22:38:15,292 a.b.c DEBUG    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A debug message
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 a.b.c INFO     IP: 192.168.0.1     User: sheila   An info message with some parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: jim      A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 192.168.0.1     User: jim      A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 192.168.0.1     User: jim      A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f INFO     IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at INFO level with 2 parameters
```

Comment: Can the question's code be expanded to do this in a simpler way in settings.py? Ideally I'd insert `%(ip)` into `'format': ' {asctime} {levelname} {message} '` or similar, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @ChrisDixon You'd need to write custom code as in my example, so precisely how you update the config depends on how that's done. IMO there's enough information here for someone to implement a simpler solution in `settings.py`, but the *exact* nature of the solution is up to them.